# Laravel forgot password emails not being sent

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5

I have an extremely odd issue with Laravel emails.

Generally speaking I can send emails fine like so:

```
Mail::send('foo', $templateData,
    function (Message $message) use ($name, $email) {
        $message
            ->from('admin@example.com', 'My Example Company')
            ->to($email, $name)
            ->subject('Blah');
    }
);
```

However, when trying to reset password, an email is not sent on my production server, despite acting like it has sent (i.e. no exceptions!). It is however sent when using `mailtrap.io`.

This is how my `.env` file looks like:

```
APP_ENV=prod
APP_KEY=XXXX
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://example.co.uk

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=XXX
DB_USERNAME=XXX
DB_PASSWORD=XXX

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=XXX
MAIL_PORT=XXX
MAIL_USERNAME=XXX
MAIL_PASSWORD=XXX
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM=admin@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="My Example Company"

GOOGLE_API_KEY=XXX
```

I also tried:

```
 composer dump-autoload
 php artisan clear-compiled
 php artisan config:clear
```

But to no avail.

Interestingly, when I use `Mailer` as opposed to the `Mail` facade, the email is again not sent with no exceptions raised.

```
public function foo(Illuminate\Mail\Mailer $mailer)
{
    $mailer->send('ViewName', [],
        function (Message $message) {
            $message
                ->from('admin@example.com', 'My Example Company')
                ->to('you@example.com', 'John Smith')
                ->subject('Blah');
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you post your forgot password controller code?

Comment: It's just the default laravel forgot your password controller (Laravel 5.2, https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/5.2), made by `php artisan make:auth`  (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passwords#resetting-database). No additional changes made!

Comment: Assuming that you are using mailtrap in dev environment and another email service in production, can you verify that your production email service details are correct?

Comment: Yes because the facade version works fine.

Comment: can you show me your email template ?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue - in Laravel, if I send a simple email it's working while the default forgot password email is not - can you, please, tell me if you found the issue? EDIT! To each try I receive the success message - even if the email was not sent

Comment: @stef same happens for me with Laravel 7 & AWS SES for emails. `MAIL_FROM` is  set, regular `Mail::send` is working, but the forgot password emails are not, without any errors / exceptions. Oddly enough, same build is working just fine from localhost. Did any one of you solved this?